# How to join a table to itself on keys in different columns that can be NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a dataset(a sample 5 fields) as below.

| Start Date | Time | number1 | number2 | key1 | key2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11/21/2022 | 0:01 | 1668969012 | 413027032418217 | B3B820CE |  |
| 11/21/2022 | 0:02 |  |  |  | B3B820CE |
| 11/21/2022 | 0:03 | 1668969013 | 413027032418218 | 8EFCB769 |  |
| 11/21/2022 | 0:04 |  |  |  | 8EFCB769 |
| 11/21/2022 | 0:05 | 1668969014 | 413027032418219 | 4070A788 |  |

As you can see first two rows and second two rows can be coupled by using the string in key1 and key2. But for the last field, there is no any matching field.

Basically I need to match these couples and create a new table as below.

| Start Date | Time | End Date | Time | number1 | number2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11/21/2022 | 0:01 | 11/21/2022 | 0:02 | 1668969012 | 413027032418217 |
| 11/21/2022 | 0:03 | 11/21/2022 | 0:04 | 1668969013 | 413027032418218 |
| 11/21/2022 | 0:05 |  |  | 1668969014 | 413027032418219 |

Here what I tried so far. But this is not providing what I need. Can some one show me what is the error here.

```sql
SELECT 
    t1.start_date_time, t2.start_date_time AS end_date_time, t1.number1, t1.number2
FROM details_all AS t1
    JOIN details_all AS t2
      ON t1.key1 = t2.key2
```

Comment: Please remove the images and add data as text

Comment: What if there are 3 or more rows with the same value in key1/key2?

Comment: @Akina maximum 2 is there for key1 and key2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can some one show me what is the error here.

The error is simple - INNER JOIN will select only complete pairs.

You must gather all key values in separate subquery then join your data to it.

```
SELECT t1.start_date_time,t2.start_date_time as end_date_time,t1.number1,t1.number2
FROM ( SELECT key1 AS key FROM table
       UNION                           -- combine columns values and remove duplicates
       SELECT key2 AS key FROM table
       ) all_keys
LEFT JOIN table t1 ON all_keys.key = t1.key1
LEFT JOIN table t2 ON all_keys.key = t2.key2
```

If `key1` value is present always whereas the same value in `key2` may absent then you may use simple LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT t1.start_date_time,t2.start_date_time as end_date_time,t1.number1,t1.number2
FROM      table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2 ON t1.key1 = t2.key2
```

Comment: This has provided null values as result.

Comment: @Pathi What "this"? 2nd query differs from your one in INNER/LEFT only, so it cannot produce less rows than your query.